# How to: Cinnamon Desktop on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, cinnamon

I'm just starting to learn unix, be gentle.  I installed ubuntu 20.04 on a windows 10 pro (2004) from the ms store with the following commands:

```
from powershell as admin:

1) wsl --set-default-version 2
2) wsl -l -v
        NAME            STATE           VERSION
      * Ubuntu-20.04    Running         2
  
      if not run: wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2
  
  
in Ubuntu terminal:

3)sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
4) sudo apt-get purge xrdp
5) sudo apt install -y xrdp
6) sudo apt install -y xfce4
7) sudo apt install -y xfce4-goodies
8) sudo cp /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini.bak
9) sudo sed -i 's/3389/3390/g' /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
10) sudo sed -i 's/max_bpp=32/#max_bpp=32\nmax_bpp=128/g' /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
11) sudo sed -i 's/xserverbpp=24/#xserverbpp=24\nxserverbpp=128/g' /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
12) echo xfce4_session > ~/.xsession
13) sudo nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
      go down to bottom of file change
  
      test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
      exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession
  
     to:
      # test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
      # exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession      
      add startxfce4
  
 14) add to bottom of .bashrc
      sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp start
      clear
15) add chrome browser:
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb


16) NOPASSEWD: to sudo visudo

17) install cinnamon-desktop-environment
```

I restarted the system but I still have Xfce running and not the cinnamon desktop.  I suspect that I need to change something in the the smartwm.sh file in step 13 but don't know what to do.

Comment: Since you want to run a DE, I'd honestly suggest using a hypervisor like Hyper-V or Virtualbox. You are going to run into many many issues related to containerised desktops doing things this way, not least of which will be performance, clipboard, mouse, and focus related. There are specific tools which are provided in both virtualisation environments which will go a long way to alleviate these issues. Please, do yourself a favor and run Hyper-V or vBox. Please see [HV W10 home](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/29175/installation-of-hyper-v-on-windows-10-home.html)

Comment: As to the DE, usually a user selects DE on login, however XRDP provides its own login interface. While logged in, please try using the ubuntu logout, at which point you will be presented with the gnome login. From here you should be given the choice to select a different DE. Hope this helps.

Comment: logout from ubuntu just closes the remote login screen and doesn't bring up any other de